Wrap text around icon
I'm trying to create a layout where an icon floats to the left of some text, similar to how an image might be aligned in a block of text. I want the text to wrap around the icon, and when it overflows to a new line, it should start directly under the first line of text, not next to the icon.
This is what I would like to achieve:

This is what I currently have:

This is my code:
<div style={{width:"100%"}}>
  <IconButtonMUI
    onClick={() => {
      window.open(url, '_blank');
    }}
    size='small'
    style={{float:"left"}}
  >
    <Iconify
      width={16}
      icon="solar:map-arrow-up-bold"
    />
  </IconButtonMUI>
  <Stack
    direction="row"
    alignItems="center"
    style={{float:"none", textAlign: 'justify'}}
    sx={{
      typography: 'h6',
    }}
  >
    {marker.placeName}
  </Stack>
</div>

Thanks in advance!

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Remove the current style from both <IconButtonMUI /> and <Stack />.
You only need style={{display: 'inline'}} on the <Stack /> component.
Check the working example on CodeSandbox
